# /dev/nfs or /nfs-root does not exist

Tags: 10.10, server, nfs

I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 on a client which I'm trying to get to boot off a server running 10.10. nfs seems to work fine on the server. If I boot the server off its internal disk, I can mount filesystems on the server. My `/tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default` file looks like this:

```
LABEL linux

KERNEL vmlinuz-2.6.32-24-generic

APPEND root=/dev/nfs initrd=initrd.img-2.6.32-24-generic nfsroot=192.168.1.71:/n

fsroot ip=dhcp rw
```

When the cleint tries boot from the server, it cannot find `/dev/nfs`

Comment: the_zork, this sounds like it might be worthy of a bug report. Can you add the exact error message you're getting? You do seem to be doing it "right"